# Swipeable fragments not displaying in correct order

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have swipeable fragments structured in the following heirarchy:
[image]

Which I use to introduce the user to the app and its functions. However, when I run the app, the fragments do not render in the correct order (welcome1 -> welcome2 -> welcome3 etc.). Instead, it displays "welcome2, welcome 2, welcome 3, welcome 4" when swiping right. When I swipe left, the order is again messed up and it displays "welcome4" every time. My code is as follows:

> IntroActivity class:

```
public class IntroActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
private ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_feature);

    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

}

public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        if (position == 0) {

            Log.e("---","Position 0");
            return WelcomeFragment.newInstance("testtitle#1",R.layout.fragment_welcome_one,R.id.welcome1);

        }else if (position == 1){

            Log.e("---","Position 1");
            return WelcomeFragment.newInstance("testtitle#2", R.layout.fragment_welcome_two, R.id.welcome2);

        }else if (position == 2){

            Log.e("---","Position 2");
            return WelcomeFragment.newInstance("testtitle#3", R.layout.fragment_welcome_three, R.id.welcome3);

        }else if (position == 3){

            Log.e("---","Position 3");
            return WelcomeFragment.newInstance("testtitle#4", R.layout.fragment_welcome_four, R.id.welcome4);

        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 4;
    }

    }
}
```

> WelcomeFragment class:

```
public class WelcomeFragment extends Fragment {

static String mTitle;
static int mLayoutID;
static int mTitleID;

public WelcomeFragment() {
}

public static WelcomeFragment newInstance(String title, int layoutID, int titleID) {

    WelcomeFragment mWelcomeFragment = new WelcomeFragment();

    mTitle = title;
    mLayoutID = layoutID;
    mTitleID = titleID;

    return mWelcomeFragment;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(mLayoutID,container,false);
    TextView textView = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(mTitleID);
    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Thin.ttf");
    textView.setText(mTitle);
    textView.setTypeface(font);

    return rootView;
    }
}
```

I am unable to pinpoint what is causing my fragments to draw incorrectly, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your newInstance method is not correct, as well as your static member variables.

Make the variables private and not static

```
private String mTitle;
private int mLayoutID;
private int mTitleID;
```

and change your newInstance method to

```
public static WelcomeFragment newInstance(String title, int layoutID, int titleID) {
    WelcomeFragment mWelcomeFragment = new WelcomeFragment();

    mWelcomeFragment.mTitle = title;
    mWelcomeFragment.mLayoutID = layoutID;
    mWelcomeFragment.mTitleID = titleID;

    return mWelcomeFragment;
}
```

Consider checking out [my tutorial](https://medium.com/@nilan/separate-back-navigation-for-a-tabbed-view-pager-in-android-459859f607e4#.828dcbouu) for an in-depth explanation of working with view pagers as well as a working example on GitHub.